# ¿Cómo guardar dos o más valores en un mismo HashMap en java?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, hashmap

Estoy empezando a ver `HashMap`, funcionan con una **Key** y un **Value**, pero, ¿Cómo hago para guardar más de un valor en un mismo `HashMap`?

```
    public void imprimir(nodo_pais Raiz,DefaultComboBoxModel modCombo, HashMap tablaHash){
        if(Raiz != null){
            imprimir(Raiz.getIzquierda(), modCombo, tablaHash);
            modCombo.addElement(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre());
            tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento().getNombre()+"");
            tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento().getCodigo()+"");
            tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento().getDescuento()+"");
            tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento().getLanguage()+"");
            tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento().getCapital()+"");
            tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento().getCurrency()+"");
            imprimir(Raiz.getDerecha(), modCombo,tablaHash);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: mire este enlace https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-duplicate-keys

Answer (score 0):

`nodo_pais.getElemento()` se ve que ya es un tipo de dato abstracto, así que puedes usarlo como valor y algún valor discriminante en él como llave.

```
        tablaHash.put(Raiz.getElemento().getNombre(), Raiz.getElemento());
```

Por lo que si quieres que el compilador lo revise por tí, podrías modificar el tipo de tu tablaHash a

```
HashMap<String, Elemento> tablaHash
```

De esta manera siempre verificará que la llave sea un string y el valor dea del tipo de elemento que contiene Raiz (que como verás asumí que es un tipo llamado `Elemento`).